# How prove the constant term of $\left(1+x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^p\equiv1\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: analysis, number-theory

if $p>3$ is odd prime number,show that:
the constant term of $$\left(1+x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^p\equiv1\pmod {p^2}$$

My try: since
$$(1+x+\dfrac{1}{x})^p=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}x^{k-2j}$$

so when $k=2j$,then the term is constant.
But how prove this constant $\equiv 1\pmod {p^2}$?

Comment: Perhaps you can use Wilson's theorem in the form $\frac1{(p-k)!}\equiv(-1)^k(k-1)!\pmod p$.

Answer (score 0):

For $p=2$, $(1+x+\frac{1}{x})^2=x^2+2x+3+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$.

$3\equiv 1\ (mod\ 4)$ ???

Comment: $1\rightarrow 1$, $2\rightarrow 3$, $3\rightarrow 7$, $4\rightarrow 19, 5\rightarrow 51, 6\rightarrow 141$

Comment: It seems to be true for all primes $> 3$.

Comment: Oh,sorry,I have edit it

Comment: More insight here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html